# building aws-lambda-builders for use with samcli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sam-cli

I would like to make some changes to the [aws-lambda-builders](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-builders) Python library and then use that modified lib in [samcli](https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli)  I've read over the developers docs for each separately, but I can't see how to integrate changes from one to the other.

I would think I could fork both and modify samcli to require my forked aws-lambda-builders but I can't see how to do that.  I'm not at all familiar with the build system used by each.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.